# Retrieve actor id and their names with their addresses in Sakila DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to extract the address against each actor id but the Sakila databse doesn't have a direct relationship with actors and addresses. Hence, I did some nesting in my code and it got complex.This is my code so far.

```
             SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name, address
FROM sakila.actor, sakila.address
WHERE address in (SELECT address
FROM sakila.address
WHERE address_id in (SELECT address_id 
FROM sakila.store
WHERE store_id in (SELECT store_id
FROM sakila.inventory
WHERE inventory_id in (SELECT inventory_id 
FROM sakila.film
WHERE film_id in (SELECT film_id 
FROM sakila.film_actor
WHERE actor_id in (SELECT actor_id
FROM sakila.actor) ) ) ) ) );
```

and I also attached the ERD.

[image: SAKILA DB ERD]

Comment: Skip the nested subqueries. Switch to `JOIN`!

Comment: From the ERD, it does not look like actors have addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The ERD you showed us does not have any relationship between actor and address. It stores addresses for customers and staff. I suppose if an actor also happened to be a customer or staffer, you might be able to get their address.

Your query will retrieve the addresses of customers and staff for stores that stock any film by the actor in question.

If you require contact information for screen actors, IMDB.com offers a premium paid service for that. It gets you their agents.